# Cloud Endpoints Error in Running ESP locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to run Cloud Endpoints ESP container locally on my Mac fallowing the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/running-esp-localdev.

I could deploy the endpoint configuration to GCP using the openapi yaml file. But some how the ESP container could not get the service definitions from Service management API.

I have looked at the ESP container logs, it has go below errors. Am I missing something?

> ```
> 2018/09/13 21:29:38[error]11#11: Failed to download rollouts: UNAVAILABLE: Failed to connect to the service management, Response body:
> 2018/09/13 21:30:08 [error] 11#11: servicemanagement.googleapis.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)
> 2018/09/13 21:30:08 [error] 11#11: servicemanagement.googleapis.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)
> 2018/09/13 21:30:08 [error] 11#11: servicemanagement.googleapis.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)
> 2018/09/13 21:30:38 [error] 11#11: servicemanagement.googleapis.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)
> 2018/09/13 21:30:38 [error] 11#11: servicemanagement.googleapis.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)
> 2018/09/13 21:30:38 [error] 11#11: servicemanagement.googleapis.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)
> ```

Comment: Could you specify if you were able to deploy the docker and the Kubernetes cluster? Is not clear to me at which point or after what operation it failed.

Answer (score 0):

`Operation timed out` errors imply that there may be a networking issue with your ESP container. Try running:

```
$ docker run byrnedo/alpine-curl curl -sI servicemanagement.googleapis.com
```

If you see `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` then you can eliminate any issues with your docker networking setup; otherwise try following the troubleshooting guide at https://success.docker.com/article/troubleshooting-container-networking.

Comment: I am getting HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found, which means there is no issue with docker network setup, but still the ESP does not work